# Excel x64Solution() VBA runs and freezes up

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and I took over from someone who has left the company. When trying to debug his VBA code, I noticed that it's hanging up at the Private Function per the code below. I'm using Windows 10 and Excel 2019. Any guidance will be much appreciated. Here is the code:

````
Private Function x64Solution()
    Dim w
    On Error Resume Next
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "%systemroot%\syswow64\mshta.exe about:""about:<head><script>moveTo(-32000,-32000);document.title='ScriptControl'</script><hta:application showintaskbar=no /><object id='shell' classid='clsid:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2'><param name=RegisterAsBrowser value=1></object><script>shell.putproperty('',document.parentWindow);</script></head>""", 0, False
    Do: For Each w In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows: Set x64Solution = w.GetProperty(""): If Err.Number = 0 Then Exit Function:
    Err.Clear: Next w: Loop
End Function```
````

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? Have you debugged it - which statement hangs, or is it trapped in an endless loop? You should split the `Do`-line into separate lines, no reason to put multiple statements on one line. All I can see is that the code tries to create an (invisible) web browser - I will for sure not try this on my computer.

Comment: Please include the specific error reported when the code fails - this helps other users find the resolution to this error.

Comment: This is a terrible, terrible thing. You should run far away from this ancient evil. It's using the local `Hypertext Markup Language Application` to pop a GUI that is constructed on the fly, using code. You should rewrite this from scratch. If you can tell us what it is supposed to do, we could point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Josiah, No error message is returned, it just hangs up. It look like it stay in the following loop:     ```Do: For Each w In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows: Set x64Solution = w.GetProperty(""): If Err.Number = 0 Then Exit Function:
    Err.Clear: Next w: Loop```

Comment: This is part of a script that is used for web scraping data from an internal website. It tried to debug it and it looks like the variable "w" never gets set by the Shell script. It shows that the value at every step. How do I figure out what the Shell script is doing?